# Call Amazon notification service on Play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I want to send a message from Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) using Play framework, and I read that I have to use WS for REST APIs. However, I am confused on how to do this. Can anyone help me work this out?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to add SNS SDK to your project by adding the following line into your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-sns" % "1.11.271"
```

then use your service by injecting it with your controller, your service should be something like:

```
@Singleton
public final class AmazonSNSService {
    // logging always a good thing to do
    private final Logger.ALogger logger = Logger.of(this.getClass());
    // this is what you have to use
    private final com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS snsClient;
    private final String AMAZON_ARN;    
    @Inject
    public AmazonSNSService(Configuration configuration) { // or Config if play 2.6 and later
        // I set the aws config in application.conf and I read them here
        final String AWS_ACCESS_KEY = configuration.getString("aws_access_key");
        final String AWS_SECRET_KEY = configuration.getString("aws_secrect_key");
        snsClient = AmazonSNSClient.builder()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)))
                .build();
        AMAZON_ARN = configuration.getString("amazon_arn_config_key");
    }

}
```

then you can use `snsClient` with methods you do want, for creating a topic:

```
public void createTopic(String topicName) {
    String topicARN = AMAZON_ARN + ":" + topicName;
    if (doesTopicExists(topicARN)) {
        logger.debug("TopicArn - already Exists" + topicARN);
    } else {
        //create a new SNS topic
        CreateTopicRequest createTopicRequest = new CreateTopicRequest(topicName);
        CreateTopicResult createTopicResult = snsClient.createTopic(createTopicRequest);

        //get request id for CreateTopicRequest from SNS metadata
        ResponseMetadata topicResponse = snsClient.getCachedResponseMetadata(createTopicRequest);
        logger.debug("CreateTopicArn - " + createTopicResult.getTopicArn());
    }
}
```

And another example to subscribe to the topic:

```
public String subscribeToTopic(String topicName, String deviceEndpointARN) {

    String topicARN = AMAZON_ARN + ":" + topicName;
    //if topic does not exists create topic then subscribe
    if (!doesTopicExists(topicARN)) {
        createTopic(topicName);
    }
    return subscribeToTopic(topicARN, deviceEndpointARN);
}
```

Want push to the topic?:

```
public void publishToTopic(String message, String topicName) {

    String topicARN = AMAZON_ARN + ":" + topicName;
    //if topic does not exists create topic then publish to topic
    // or throw an exception, maybe it does not make sense to push to the topic that have no subscribers at all.
    if (!doesTopicExists(topicARN)) {
        createTopic(topicName);
    }
    //publish to an SNS topic
    PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(topicARN, message);
    publishRequest.setMessageStructure("json");
    PublishResult publishResult = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
    //print MessageId of message published to SNS topic
    logger.debug("Push Notification sent to TOPIC [" + topicARN + "] MessageId - [" + publishResult.getMessageId() + "] Message Body: " + message);

}
```

And this is how I check if the topic exists or not:

```
private boolean doesTopicExists(String topicARN) {
    String nextToken = null;
    do {
        ListTopicsRequest request = new ListTopicsRequest();
        request.setNextToken(nextToken);

        ListTopicsResult listTopicsResult = snsClient.listTopics();
        List<Topic> topics = listTopicsResult.getTopics();

        for (Topic topic : topics) {
            if (topic.getTopicArn().equals(topicARN)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        nextToken = request.getNextToken();
    } while (nextToken != null);
    return false;
}
```

For more, check java doc of them and search for examples,
Have fun!

Comment: yes! it is already working prod environment as well, what the problem with it? it is java anyway if you mean https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWS it will be applicable but more headache to handle things, SDK will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Sure,  so this SDK, I have to download for Play?

Comment: If I was to use the WS, do you know how you would go about doing it?

Comment: for SDK, just add that line to the build.sbt file, it will download that for you! using `WS` is really too broad, it is about building service and adding a lot of lines just to handle responses, errors, how to send, and collecting data and nested calls and so on, why you want that? anyway, if play document did not help you with this, I really can't help you either, I think you need to start with simple code and using examples provided from document to start with.

Comment: Also, there is no language called Play, it is a framework that built on Java/Scala, why I feel you think they are both different things like Java not going to work with play!